# Read multiple files with C++

Tags: c++

I would like to edit the below code to look at and read several other files in the proc directory. May I get some guidance on how to improve this code to look at other proc files other than just the uptime. Thank you.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib> // for exit()

int main()
{
using namespace std;

// ifstream is used for reading files
// We'll read from a file called Sample.dat
ifstream inf("/proc/uptime");

// If we couldn't open the input file stream for reading
if (!inf)
{
    // Print an error and exit
    cerr << "Uh oh, file could not be opened for reading!" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

// While there's still stuff left to read
while (inf)
{
    // read stuff from the file into a string and print it
    std::string strInput;
    getline(inf, strInput);
    cout << strInput << endl;
}


    return 0;

    // When inf goes out of scope, the ifstream
    // destructor will close the file
}
```

Comment: Put your reading code in a function. Get all of your filenames in a vector. Iterate over the vector calling your function for each filename.

Comment: You could try changing the filename `"/proc/uptime"` to the name of the another files you want to read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is written with a function instead

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib> // for exit()

using namespace std;

void readfile(string file)
{

   ifstream inf (file.c_str());

    if (!inf)
    {
        // Print an error and exit
        cerr << "Uh oh, file could not be opened for reading!" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    while (inf)
    {
        std::string strInput;
        getline(inf, strInput);
        cout << strInput << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << "-------------------obtaining Totaltime and Idletime----------------" << endl;
    readfile("/proc/uptime");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks user 2220115. That helped.